# Java applets destroy() method

Tags: java

Do java free up resources even if we don't override the destroy method?

What happens if we don't override `stop()` and `destroy()` methods?

Will freeing up of resources happen on its own?

Comment: How are you planning on allocating resources with an Applet? To put it another way, what browser still supports Applets?

Comment: The Java Applet (really an embedded Java Web Start app) effectively runs in its own isolation container. All JVM-managed resources will be disposed when it ends. As with most GC-based language runtimes there is no usually need to "free" anything. However, `stop` doesn't mean the applet has ended.

Comment: I did not actually get you by your question, Iam in a learning stage, I am using chrome browser, and wanted to know that what happens if we don't use destroy() method, for actions in init() method. @Elliot Frisch

Comment: @Gnaneshwar [Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).

Comment: Thanks all, I understood that if we don't use destroy, JVM will take care of. Once again thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Destroy:** `destroy()` method is called by the browser just before an applet is terminated. Your applet will override this method if it needs to perform any cleanup prior to its destruction.

A subclass of Applet should override this method if it has any operation that it wants to perform before it is destroyed. For example, an applet with threads would use the init method to create the threads and the destroy method to kill them.

The implementation of this method provided by the Applet class does nothing.

**Stop:** `stop()` method is called by the browser to suspend execution of the applet. Once stopped, an applet is restarted when the browser calls start( ).

A subclass of Applet should override this method if it has any operation that it wants to perform each time the Web page containing it is no longer visible. For example, an applet with animation might want to use the start method to resume animation, and the stop method to suspend the animation.

The implementation of this method provided by the Applet class does nothing.

and Ya.. JVM will take care of resource deallocation by garbage collection mechanism. It will free the resources which are no longer referenced .

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html

Comment: Thanks all once again

Answer (score 1):

1. People seldom use Java applets anymore (now I wish we could make them stop using Flash!).
2. It was never actually "mandatory" to override stop() or destroy(): it was just a convenient way to do any custom "cleanup", if you wished.
3. As user2864740 correctly noted, applets run in a JVM ... and any resources allocated are automagically freed when the JVM exits.  Whether you override your applet's stop()/destroy() or not.

Comment: Thank for your valuable answer.